# font styles are not Changing neither numbers in android

Tags: android, localization, font-style

I'm getting stuck in this for two days i hope i find a solution..
I'm trying to localize my app (Arabic, and English)
the localization mechanism is working fine, the words, layout directions are working well,
However there are two things are not being localized the first one is **numbers**. 
numbers are not being localized to arabic.
the second one is **Font style** font style are not being localized neither.
**BUT** it change the font style and number to arabic, only if i reinstalled the app using my USB and the configuration was in Arabic before the installing. here is my code

```
public static void changeLocale(Activity context, Bundle... bundles) {

        MedfastSharedPreferencesHelper sharakehSharedPreference = new MedfastSharedPreferencesHelper(context);
        String lang = sharakehSharedPreference.getKey("locale");
        Locale locale = null;
        if (null == lang) {
            locale = new Locale(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage());
            lang = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
            if (locale.getDisplayLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("English")) {
                locale = new Locale("ar");
                lang = "ar";
            } else {
                locale = new Locale("en");
                lang = "en";
            }

        } else if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("ar")) {
            lang = "en";
            locale = new Locale("en");

        } else if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("en")) {
            lang = "ar";
            locale = new Locale("ar");

        }
        sharakehSharedPreference.setKey("locale", lang);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ((Activity) context).getClass());
        if (null != bundles && bundles.length > 0 && null != bundles[0])
            intent.putExtras(bundles[0]);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        context.finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, android does not support font as resource, so i had do create 6 classes in order to customize my fonts and check weather if the locale is Arabic or english, and depending on the locale i load the font,  unlike drawable in android

Answer (score 0):

Hey as Basil Battikhi said, the font does not apply to numbers, But there are some solutions:

1: Create your own custom textView to be able to change things you want.

2: Define this in strings.xml

```
<string name="number">%1d</string>
```

and set number to your textView like this:

```
textCoin.text = getString(R.string.number, it)
```

3: You can use this code for formating your textView for numbers:

```
public static String convertEngNumToFa(String number) {
    if (AppConstants.FA_LOCALE == DataManager.Language.fa) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            for (char _ch : number.toCharArray()) {
                if ((int) _ch > 47 && (int) _ch < 58) {
                    int x = (int) _ch + 1632 - 48;
                    char ch = (char) (x);

                    res.append(Character.toString(ch));
                } else {
                    res.append(Character.toString(_ch));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return res.toString();
        }
        return res.toString();
    } else return number;
}
```